# PHP cannot automatically use function result as array (in PHP 5.3)

Tags: php, php-5.3

When I try to run something like

```
getParent($child)[0]->user
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /.....
```

The problem can be avoided if I do something like this:

```
$get_parent = getParent($child);
$parent = $get_parent[0]->user;
```

Is there a better way to do in php 5.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, before PHP5.4, you have to do that.

Array dereferencing comes from PHP 5.4.

But if `getParent` return an object which implement the [ArrayAccess interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php#class.arrayaccess), you could chain it with:

```
$parent = getParent($child)->offsetGet(0)->user;
```

If it just return an array, then a temp variable is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there **is** a way to achieve that without temporary variable. But I definitely wouldn't recommend to use it (because, yes, it's one-liner and it's not using temporary variable, but no - it's not readable):

```
function getParent($child=null)
{
   //mock:
   return array(
      (object)(array('user'=>'foo', 'data'=>'fee')),
      (object)(array('user'=>'bar', 'data'=>'bee')),
   );
};

//array(null) will have 1 key, 0;
//however, to get another offset N, use array(N => null) instead
$result = array_shift(array_intersect_key(getParent('baz'), array(null)))->user;
```

-so use temporary variable if your version in <5.4

Where it *may* be helpful - is in debugger, where you're forced to use "one-liners" to check some expression(s)

Answer (score 0):

There is no better way to do it when using PHP version < 5.4.

If you still want to use one line instead of 2 and you always want to get the first element, you can try the following

```
echo reset(getParent($child))->user;
```

This reset the array pointer to 0 and returns the value.

Comment: It also gives an `E_STRICT` warning because the return value of `getParent` is passed in by reference.